# How to DRY up my Rails controller and avoid declaring this variable in every action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

To display a list of collections which belong to a user, I have:

```
if user_signed_in?
  @user_collections = current_user.collections.paginate(page: params[:collections_page], :per_page => 10)
end
```

and

```
<%= render @user_collections %>
```

However, I want to refresh this list of collections whenever I do some sort of action like add to the collection, create a new collection, etc. with Ajax. It seems like I have to initialize @user_collections in every action.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are you calling different route for every action ?

Comment: is user collection displayed in every page like a header or footer. If not why do you feel to add @user_collections in every action?

Comment: The site is mostly one page which behaves like a web application by updating with Ajax through different routes/actions. Collections should always be rendered on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @felixbuenemann mentioned, you can DRY the logic.

For example,

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_user_collections

  private
  def load_user_collections
    if user_signed_in?
      @user_collections ||= current_user.collections.paginate(page: params[:collections_page], :per_page => 10)
    end
  end
end
```

if you worried about heavy sql query, How about cache?

```
if user_signed_in?
  @user_collections = Rails.cache.fetch("#{current_user.id}", expires_in: 5.minutes) do
    current_user.collections.paginate(page: params[:collections_page], :per_page => 10)
  end
end
```

Comment: you're missing a couple of ends there

Comment: The cache key needs to include a prefix and the `:collections_page` query param to be unique. Since ActiveRecord relations are lazily evaluated you should also add a `to_a` call to turn it into an array of records.

Comment: And since the user is actively manipulating the collection you would need additional logic to remove the cache entry after updates.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions everybody. I've marked Junsuk's answer for being the most thorough.

Answer (score 1):

Another practice to DRY the logic:

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
  def get_user_collections
    @user_collections = user_collections(params[:collections_page], 10) if user_signed_in?
  end
private
  def user_collections(collections_page, users_per_page)
    current_user.collections.paginate(page: collections_page, :per_page => users_per_page)
  end
end
```

For more you can look up to in this [link](https://blog.codeminer42.com/controller-best-practices-dont-hide-instance-variables-5e8bf067156).

Comment: Passing also a variable for number per pages, to be more flexible: `:per_page => per_page`

Comment: Thanks, for the suggestion @iGian, will edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `before_action` to share behavior for multiple actions.

See the [Rails Guides on Filters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) for more info.

Comment: This solution works for me, although I'm wondering if I'm doing something fundamentally poor to have to use before_action.

Comment: You could also use a memoized method with the logic and mark it as a helper method to be able to call it from views, if you think that's cleaner.